# Maintaining state of an iFrame page in various browser windows/tabs through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, state

I have a page (say 'basepage') in which there is one iFrame. In this iFrame, there are various divs which are displayed and are made hidden based on some criterion at run-time. This criterion is nothing but AJAX call to some other external API through another page (say 'page2') . If the API returns (say 'x') value, div1 is displayed (rest are made hidden) and if it returns (say 'y') value, div2 is displayed (rest hidden) and so on.

The problem is, if I open just 1 browser window of basepage everything works fine but opening multiple windows/tabs of basepage does not reflect the value across all pages.

Consider the following steps:

1. Open basepage. Default settings are displayed.
2. Open page2. API gets called called and it returns 'x'. In basepage 'div1' block is displayed and rest are hidden.
3. Open basepage in another tab/window of same browser. Default settings are displayed while this should not occur. It should display div1 with rest hidden.

Hope I have made my problem clear enough for all you people to understand. This has to be done with help of javascript/jQuery only. Kindly help me out.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Could you post some code here?

Comment: "Default settings are displayed while this should not occur." But seems like default behaviour. Each new page is a kind of new instance of your page. If you want to keep 'state' of iframe, i think you need to code your logic server side. Maybe i misundrestood your problem here.

Comment: @roasted - Since the API has returned value 'x' now, it should not display the default settings. Consider two phone on same lines. If someone is ringing your number, both the phones should ring not only one. Similarly until the value of API resets back to original value (which it does after 60 seconds), all windows/tabs should display div1 only.

This is the best analogy I can come of right now.

Comment: @harsha - I can post some code but it will take some time because I would have to remove many other functionality.

Comment: But API is returning default value or not? Is it your own API or you don't have any control on it?  BTW, don't be afraid to use some of your time to post relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a day of struggle on Lord Google, I have come to know that I am actually looking for is '[WebStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)' introduced in HTML5. Too bad this won't work for Old Browsers though but at least I am good to go further.

Thanks so much people for looking into this. :-)

Answer (score -1):

In my projects I use window.name property to identify browser tabs. Guess it's a good point for you to start.

Comment: @harsha Not really is, but as i mentioned - it's an start off point. And as I know it's the only way to separate different browser windows via JS.